# WiX Toolset not being recognized in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019

I have installed WiX toolset and the WiX Visual Studio Extension, but only the extension is recognized. It does not recognize that I have the toolset downloaded. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling in different orders and I have restarted both Visual Studio and my computer multiple times. Any suggestions?

***Here is a screen shot of my errors:***

[image: VS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you show don't provide enough evidence that WiX is not installed.  It does suggest that your console application project is missing a reference to the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll assembly which is typically found in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks for the help!